# E PROBLEMS when using Excel

Tags: excel

Hi my problem is everytime I use excel and place an E in the cell with numbers it turns it into a mathematical equation.
Example: 6807E02 turns to 6.81E+05. Totally driving me insane. Someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Excel assumes you are entering a number using a variant of [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) called *E Notation*.  When you enter **6807E02**, Excel assumes you are talking about the number **680,700** (6807 x 10 ^ 2).  Excel has it's own method of formatting scientific notation, which is to always put the decimal to the right of the first digit, and end with the E (the multiple of 10) to the far right.  That's why you're seeing **6.81E+05** (the display rounds to two digits after the decimal, but the number is still the same).

If you're intentionally trying to type in the text value "6807E02", you can either set the cell's data type to "Text" (Image below), or you can type the single apostrophe key (<kbd>'</kbd>) before you start entering the number.  If you want the number you typed in, but you don't want Excel to override your number formatting, that's unfortunately beyond my abilities.  Excel is pretty stringent with custom formatting when it comes to Scientific Notation.  You would probably end up spending far more time trying to force Excel to accept your notation as a custom format than the value doing so would add to your project.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this [link should help you](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US),

From what I can see the easiest solution would be if you put an apostrophe (') in front of the number excel will treat it as text.

For example '6807E02

Comment: I am not sure if this question belongs on SO I can see there are excel tags but I feel as though they may not be related to this type of question.